# MVC Application - Use your local DB in order to login/register

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new into MVC applications and I'm trying to learn how to connect to my local DB. I have watched lots of tutorials and I could figure it out how to change my connection string in order for the MVC to access my database. But, if I register on my MVC Application, Visual Studio creates automatically four new tables, besides my TEST database and the new user is inserted in those tables, not in the table I have set/used in connection string. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Here is my connection string:

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-K6CIG9A;Database=TEST;Trusted_Connection=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Here is how it looks my Server Explorer:
[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mQAs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to change your connection string to use `(LocalDb)\v11.0`. You can find more information in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string) article.